# How can i complete this loop?

Tags: python

So I have to create a loop that can calculate when will u investment surpass the j investment.

```
One investment is 800$
The other one is 1000$
x is how many years will it take
a is 15% yearly returns for 800$
b is 10% yearly returns for 1000$
```

```py
    u=800
    j=1000
    a=0,15
    b=0,10
    x=0

while True:

    while True:
        print(u*a)
        print(j*b)
        x+=1
     
    if j<=u :
        break
print("Uldis pārsniegs Jāni pēc %d gadiem" % (x))
```

Comment: Please update your question with a question.

Comment: @quamrana I agree. As viewing this question as part of the triage, I realize that there is no question here. Please provide one.

Answer (score 2):

try below code.
instead of while True you can use controlled loop

```
u=800
j=1000
a=0.15
b=0.10
x=0
#while u is less than j
while u<j:
    #update u
    u=u+(u*a)
    #update j
    j=j+(j*b)
    x+=1
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not saving the yearly returns from `j` and `u` in any variable. By comparing `j` and `u` in that if block you are not comparing the actual returns but the initial investment.
You should use two counters for the actual return of investment, something like this:

```
u=800
j=1000
a=0.15
b=0.10
x=0
returnFromU = 0
returnFromJ = 0
while(True):
    returnFromU += u*a
    returnFromJ += j*b
    x+=1
    if(returnFromU >= returnFromJ):
        break
print("It takes +"str(x)+" years for u investment to surpass j")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a `while` loop with a condition. It will better prevent you from running a loop forever.

I also recommend not changing `u` and `j`, but to introduce other variables to store the current value of the investment after `x` years. I use `u_x` and `j_x` for that purpose.

For calculation of the current value of the investment I use the formula for [Compound interests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest).

```
u=800
j=1000
a=0.15
b=0.10
x = 0

# Value of u and j after x years
u_x = u
j_x = j

while u_x < j_x:
    x += 1
    u_x = u * (1 + a)**x
    j_x = j * (1 + b)**x

print(f'Investment u surpassed investment j after {x} years')
```

#### Output

```
Investment u surpassed investment j after 6 years
```

---

### Direct calculation

You can also consider to directly calculate the years required for investment `u` to surpass investment `j`:

```
import math
x = math.ceil(math.log(u/j)/math.log((1+b)/(1+a)))
print(f'Investment u surpassed investment j after {x} years')
```

#### Output

```
Investment u surpassed investment j after 6 years
```